# Will MySql Workbench remove source objects after migriting

Tags: mysql, migration, workbench

I am still new to db's and i'm trying to migrate sql server db to mysql server.

Will workbench remove my source objects after migrating or will it just create a copy of it ?

Thank you for your help and time in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question unfortunately is not very specific. Surely you can use MySQL Workbench to clean your database. Besides that I'm not sure what you're updating, is it your DBMS version, MySQL Workbench software, you database layout?!

Comment: I have a sql server db sitting on one server a one empty MySql db on another.
What i am trying to achieve is copy all the tables from the sql server to MySql db but i do not want to lose the data from sql server by doing so

Comment: Please update your question and not provide necessary details like that in comments ;) However, I'm still not sure, if the one database is empty, what are you afraid of losing on that side?